# Disabling Paste option from the Context menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, contextmenu, right-click

I have one asp.net application, in which i have to **disable** or make it as  **read only** to the Paste option from the context menu. But i searched in internet. I didn't get one exact method. Please help me for resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do this.

The user's browser is their own, and as such they have the sovereign power to interact with your page however they want.  You can catch right-click events to prevent the menu from coming up; you can catch keypress events to stop Ctrl-V (and Shift-Insert, which is often forgotten) from being registered.  However, you can't remove the Edit -> Paste menu option, which works within the browser and subverts Javascript altogether.

Not to mention that the user could just disable Javascript temporarily, paste into the field, then reenable Javascript if they wanted.

Even if you're happy with the limitations, you cannot modify the actual context menu, only prevent the right click from registering at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose isn't possible to disable a single item on context menu, so I think you should try to disable the whole context menu, e.g.

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

∎ Another way of solving this pesky problem,
using JavaScript's Object-Oriented characteristics

```
<div class="ro-editable">
  <span.....</...
  <pre....</...
</div>

<script>
  function make_editable_readonly(element){
    element.backup_innerHTML = element.innerHTML;   /* backup before editable. */
    element.contenteditable = "true";               /* editable. CTRL+A is usable (FUN!) */

    element.onautocomplete                          /* what in the world could change the content? actually lot!.. */
  = element.onchange 
  = element.oncontextmenu 
  = element.oncopy 
  = element.oncuechange 
  = element.oncut 
  = element.ondrag 
  = element.ondragend 
  = element.ondrop 
  = element.onemptied 
  = element.onkeyup 
  = element.onmouseup 
  = element.onpaste 
  = element.onreset = function restore(){ 
                        if (element.innerHTML !== element.backup_innerHTML) 
                          element.innerHTML = element.backup_innerHTML;
                      };
  }

  make_editable_readonly(
    document.querySelector('div.ro-editable')
  );
</script>
```

∎ *Easy! Right?  (and with **no** y key-event "filtering" ☺):*

### ∎ And here is a [JSFiddle to **play<sup>⚽</sup> with**](https://jsfiddle.net/za55xv7j/)

∎ taken from [iCompile - ContentEditable And "ReadOnly"? YES! ☕](http://icompile.eladkarako.com/contenteditable-and-readonly/)